# Python initialize np.zeros() and set value in index(x) in one line

Tags: python, numpy

Is any way to do this

```
x = np.zeros(10)
x.itemset(7,1)
```

in one line like this

```
y = np.zeros(10).itemset(7,1)
```

?

Current output

```
print(x)
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

print(y)
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.bincount` for some added flexibility:

```
np.bincount([7],[1],10)
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.])
```

For example you can set multiple values:

```
np.bincount([1,4,7],[2.1,5,-1],8)
array([ 0. ,  2.1,  0. ,  0. ,  5. ,  0. ,  0. , -1. ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Well not directly no, as `itemset()` is a non-returning function (thats why y is None). Is it really that bad to have two lines though? 
You could do it without using numpy and list comprehension:

```
 y = [1.0 if i == 7 else 0.0 for i in range(10)]
```

However as I said, I would just go with the extra line as this is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

The `x.itemset(7,1)` do this operation **in place**. It means that it changes x, but returns None.

For this reason, you can't use `y = np.zeros(10).itemset(7,1)`...

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Eric's answer. However if you insist on one line, since `itemset` works in place, and setting multiple instances of the same mutable (such as numpy array) in a list makes all instances point to the same array we can do something like that:

```
y = [x.itemset(7, 1) if i == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate([np.zeros(10)]*2)][1]
print(y)
```

On the first run (`i == 0`) it sets the array's item (and returns `None`), and on the second run (`i == 1`) it just returns the array.